# Is it possible to set kendo UI configurations in a loop?

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui

Here's an example of a situation I'm facing:

I have a bunch of kendoNumericTextBoxes added like so

```
<input type="number" id="test1" class="kendoText" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="<databind>" />    
<input type="number" id="test2" class="kendoText" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="<databind>" />   
<input type="number" id="test3" class="kendoText" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="<databind>" />
```

and then a script which triggers on `$(document).ready` to set the configurations for each one, e.g.

```
$("#test1").kendoNumericTextBox({
     format: "c0",
     spinners: false,
     max: 1000000000,
     min: 0
});
```

Since I was setting the configuration to the exact same values for many of these, my immediate thought was to automate this through a loop

```
var tags = ["#test1", "#test2", "#test3"];

tags.forEach(tag => 
    $(tag).kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "c0",
        spinners: false,
        max: 1000000000,
        min: 0
    });
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and I can't seem to find a reason why it wouldn't work. Any ideas on what might be causing it, and how I could fix it?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can provide, a link to snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var kendoInputs = $( '.kendoText' );
    kendoInputs.kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: 'c0',
        spinners: false,
        max: 1000000000,
        min: 0
    });
});
```

Instead of you declaring `id` for each input in an array, you can use `class` attribute to target all elements that have that `class`.

Also you have duplicate `id's` in you html example, which may also be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to tweak it to instead be `var kendoInputs = $('[data-role="numerictextbox"]')` and it worked perfectly. I think using the class caused some issues with display since it generates child elements with the same class name

Comment: Glad could be of help :)